# Можно ли рассматривать фонему как непустое множество звуков?

Tags: фонетика

Вопрос сформулирован в заголовке.

Comment: Странно как-то: литература для Вас - пустое множество, а фонема нет.

Comment: Вам кажется[, что литература для меня пустое множество].

Comment: Ага, Галактион начал изучать логику предикатов...

Answer (score 1):

Фонема - это уж точно не пустое множество звуков - хотя бы один звук там имеется. Различные теории как раз и рассматривают содержание этого множества. Фактически мы имеем явление (фонетическое чередование звуков) и пытаемся описать его, то есть смоделировать. (Любое описание - это всего лишь модель явления, где учтены его главные свойства).

МФШ зациклилась на том, что фонема - это звукоряд, содержащий ВСЕ звуки (доминанту, вариации, варианты), то есть  множество имеет максимальный объём. Но это не есть хорошо: желательно "отделить зерна от плевел", то есть оставить в этом множестве только смыслоразличительные звуковые формы (для гласных фонем это основной звук-доминанта и его мягкая вариация, то есть те звуки, которые мы слышим в ударной позиции). А все безударные звуки (Ь, Ъ и др.)отправить в другое множество.

Тогда реальное слово будет состоять из звуков двух видов: смыслоразличительные фонемы и звуки с неполной различительной способностью. Например: с(а)ю(с) - здесь две фонемы и два звука. Фонемы обозначаются буквами сразу, а звуки с неполной различительной способностью должны быть проверены, заменены фонемами и затем обозначены буквами. Вот и вся фонология.

Это простейшая МОДЕЛЬ явления, доступная младшим школьникам, но она работает четко и наглядно, обеспечивая поставленную задачу: обозначать буквами только звуки-фонемы, ответственные за СМЫСЛ морфем и слов.

Comment: Почти ничего не понял. Например:

1) "Фонема - это ... не пустое множество звуков ...",

2) "... фонема - это звукоряд, содержащий ВСЕ звуки (доминанту, вариации, варианты), то есть множество имеет максимальный объём",

3) "... реальное слово будет состоять из звуков двух видов: смыслоразличительные фонемы и звуки с неполной различительной способностью."

4) "... простейшая МОДЕЛЬ явления ... работает четко и наглядно, обеспечивая поставленную задачу: обозначать буквами только звуки-фонемы, ответственные за СМЫСЛ морфем и слов."

Пожалуй, пойду выпью немного ликёра.

Comment: 300 капель эфирной валерьянки (вот они, трамваи-то!)

Comment: Например, есть у нас фонема О: "вол" - здесь фонема О представлена основным звуком О (доминантой), "вёл" - здесь она представлена мягкой вариацией. Обе звуковые формы ударные и имеют полную различительную способность. В слове "волы" по правилам орфоэпии произносится звук, похожий на А. Это вариант фонемы О с неполной различительной способностью - таким же звуком может быть представлена и фонема А. В слове "грохот" фонема О во втором слоге представлена звуком Ъ - его различительная способность еще меньше.

Comment: Фонема З имеет доминанту З и варианты: С твердый и З/С мягкие: моро(с), гво(зь)дик, мо(сь)тик. Так можно пройтись по всем фонемам, определив основную форму и возможных заместителей. В МФШ считают, что фонема - это полный звукоряд: основной звук и все заместители. Такое определение фонемы возможно, но неудобно для практической орфографии. Здесь лучше считать, что фонема - это один основной звук (гласные фонемы при этом имеют твердую и мягкую разновидности). Остальные звуки определяются как звуки с неполной различительной способностью, и их без проверки нельзя обозначать буквами.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.